# Does anybody know why HP offers only SATA SSD drives?

Tags: hardware, storage, hp, ssd

HP offers SSD drives for their ProLiant range of servers but they only come with SATA interfaces. This is strange because in the past drives with SATA interfaces were Second Class Citizens in the server area.

Is there any technical/engineering reason for this? I missed this years product update presentation and couldn't find any definitive information online.

Overview over HP SSD drives: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13415_na/13415_na.HTML

Comment: You might be interested that STEC the top provider today of enterprise-class SSDs has some [SSDs with SAS Interface](http://www.stec-inc.com/interface/sas.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do, part numbers AE184AS, AE225AS & AE226AS are all Fibre Channel attached SSDs (in 73, 200 and 400GB capacities respectively).

What they don't offer for sale, today, are SAS attached SSDs - simple because no manufacturer they use are making them yet.

Answer (score 2):

It simply is like that because most SSD simply come with SATA. Plus, with their IOPS capability they dleiver hugh throughput on SATA.

Heck, high end onces TOTALLY SATURATE the SATA link. With random access. SSD are atotalyl different ballpark - no need to go fancy interface wise.